# Set application pool iis express 7.5 for application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

How to change application pool identity in IIS Express 7.5 for an application in applicationHost.config file for perticulat application from commandline.

I need to set "Clr2ClassicAppPool" application pool for my application.

Don't want to change default setting in applicationhost.config file, Default applcation pool set in applicationhost.config see below

```
<applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
```

When i replace ir with below code then my application run perfecttly.

```
<applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr2ClassicAppPool" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about command line but you can change the app pool defaults for just your site in `applicationHost.config`:

```
<site name="MySite" id="9">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2ClassicAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\path\to\MySite" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8280:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

This blog post talks about various commandline options while running IISExpress: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line